# Если ты сейчас уйдешь, то, возвратившись, найдешь меня мертвой

Tags: синтаксис

Проверьте пожалуйста: чем выражено и чем является в предложении?

*Если ты сейчас уйдешь, то, **возвратившись**, найдешь меня мертвой.*

Деепричастие, обособленное обстоятельство. Оно несет в себе что-то временное tipo "*когда вернешься*"...?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

> Деепричастие, обособленное обстоятельство. Оно несет в себе что-то
>   временное tipo "когда вернешься"...?

Всё так.

Answer (score 3):

Это обособленное обстоятельство времени (синтаксическая функция), выраженное деепричастием (часть речи).

Comment: ... а если смотреть глобально, можно утверждать, что по типу это предложение условное?